# Package network-manager-openvpn is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: apt, live-usb, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying out Ubuntu's live cd and have booted in from a USB. I want to check if it will work with my VPN or not. I already have Network Manager installed, but when I go to Configure VPNs, I can only see PPTP as an option, while I need to add an OpenVPN type of VPN.

Following the instructions on my VPN's [documentation](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ubuntu_openvpn) I tried to install openvpn using this:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

But I get the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package network-manager-openvpn is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'network-manager-openvpn' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? On Ubuntu 12.10 I have this package.

Comment: @Flimm I'm using 12.10 as well. But I'm on the USB and haven't yet installed Ubuntu. Could it be why its not working?

Comment: Yes, possibly. You'll need to connect to the Internet, and run `sudo apt-get update`. You'll need the "universe" repository to be enabled, check in Software Sources.

Answer (score 2):

`network-manager-openvpn` is in universe, which isn't included on the live image by default. But you can still temporarily install it in the live environment. Assuming that you're using 12.10, add this line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update`, and try `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn` again.

I'm not sure if you need to restart Network Manager after installing. If so, `sudo restart network-manager` should work.

Comment: The GUI way of adding the "universe" repository is to open Software Sources and tick "Community maintained free and open source software (universe)"