# apt-get package is not available but is referred to by another package - but cannot find that package

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to install a package with apt-get install, I'll occasionally see a message of the form

```
Package somePackage is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package somePackage has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know how to find out what package(s) it is actually referring to?

*Note:*

I looked at ["But is referred to by another package." - Finding that package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391184/but-is-referred-to-by-another-package-finding-that-package) and it suggested using `apt-cache search` to find the package that refers to it. Yet if I do this for `somePackage`, I won't get any output.

For example, `apt-cache search openoffice.org-hunspell` returns no output, but `apt-cache search gcc` returns several packages.

Edit:

There are several different packages that have caused the first part of the problem for me in the past, but the apt-cache search not turning anything up has (so far) only happened for the openoffice.org-hunspell package.

I guess that what I want to know the most is this: when I see the error message "Package somePackage has no installation candidate," I'd like to have a sure-fire way to know

1. Was it replaced with another package (in which case knowing what the new package name is would be helpful); or
2. Was it just removed altogether; or
3. Is there some problem with `/etc/apt/sources.list` that means I can't get it.

Comment: I very rarely see that message.

Comment: Is there only one package this is happening to for you, or many? And if one, which package? (`synaptic` might be another possible tool for checking packages you want to install, as well)

Comment: Bad Example - OpenOffice is now Third party, use [Libreoffice](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-writer/) instead. If you want to install it, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice). Anyway, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm on 12.04. So technically Libreoffice is already installed. Yet there doesn't seem to be a corresponding package with the libreoffice prefix. For example, there doesn't seem to be a package called "libreoffice-hunspell".

Comment: You've done an `apt-get update` right? I've heard that message can show up when a package has been removed from a repo, but you're APT cache doesn't know it yet.

Comment: When you say "what package(s) it is actually referring to" do you mean "what package(s) are referring to somePackage"?

Comment: Xen2050 points out "apt-get update" I thought during an installation process I just need to run that command once at the beginning. but re-running helped. So following the instructions step by step by step helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try running: `sudo apt-get update`](https://askubuntu.com/a/878509)

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of errors when the universe repos were not enabled (it was a minimal server  install). Enabling them solved the issue (the package were provided by such repos). HTH.

Answer (score -1):

> Package **somePackage is not available**, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

It means that a package have dependency, suggestion or recommendation to "somePackage", but **somePackage itself and any associated meta data is not available**. You should look, *by yourself*, for the replacement of somePackage (if the package was in the official repositories, it's very likely that there's a empty package that points to the replacement), in case the package has been renamed, or forget about it, in case you are trying to get a package that was removed from the repositories for any motive. There's simply no way to do this programmatically.

Comment: This is effectively a restatement of part of the question -- the questioner is aware it indicates that a package has been removed, he's trying to find a general way to determine what package is depending on the one named in the error message.

Comment: @ZeissIkon This is effectively a restatement of the answer: you can't.

Comment: May want to clarify that in your answer, then.  I didn't get that from what you wrote.