# Unable to install any package from apt (Package not available)

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

For the past week, I have been facing this issue, for many packages that I try to install from `apt`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package **package_name** is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

This issue is with every package.

Just to mention. I have tried all the solution that has been mentioned here
["But is referred to by another package." - Finding that package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391184/but-is-referred-to-by-another-package-finding-that-package).

But nothing is working. I am really stuck with this package thing.
My system.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwxgtk3.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwxgtk3.0-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a real example package name and the output of this `sudo apt policy package_name`. Also, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: what does ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` do ? . I have opened it. It contains the repo links I guess

Comment: The result of ```sudo apt policy libwxgtk3.0-dev```  is this ```ibwxgtk3.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table```

Comment: Ok, why do you think this package should be available? it is not available for me either.

Comment: Actually I am trying to build a project which has following package dependencies. ```apt-get install gawk m4 libwxgtk3.0-dev libpcre2-dev libxerces-c-dev libspdlog-dev libuchardet-dev libssh-dev libssl-dev libsmbclient-dev libnfs-dev libneon27-dev libarchive-dev cmake g++ git```

Comment: It is available for bionic, but not for focal. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libwxgtk3.0-dev. For `focal` you have `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`, not sure if it is the same. So the project documentation is for 18.04 maybe

Comment: All got solved from ```sudo apt-get update``` but ```libwxgtk3.0-dev``` is still showing this error

Comment: Is there any alternative? for ```20.04```

Comment: `libwxgtk3.0-dev` is not available for `20.04`, so it is not working is normal. Try `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`. But you might need to enable `universe` repository: `sudo apt-add-repository universe` before, because that is not enabled by default I think.

Comment: okay, thanks for the info. Got it.

Comment: Okay, It worked. Really thanks. I already had ```universe``` added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `libwxgtk3.0-dev` is not available for Ubuntu 20.04.

I guess the documentation for your project is written for Ubuntu 18.04, for which [that package name exists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libwxgtk3.0-dev).

However, you can use the replacement package [`libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev).
Note: It is `universe` repository, which you might need to enable:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

For such issues, https://packages.ubuntu.com/ is a good website to start package research.