# problem installing CLooG

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, gcc

I tried installing CLooG after reinstalling Ubuntu and i runned the following command :
`sudo apt install libcloog-isl-dev` 
but it returned me :

> Package libcloog-isl-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source 
> E: Package 'libcloog-isl-dev' has no installation candidate

the problem is this worked before and I haven't found a solution, I tried the solutions in this thread : ["is not available, but is referred to by another package" - finding that package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391184/is-not-available-but-is-referred-to-by-another-package-finding-that-package) 
I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
I don't know if this is related to https://www.cloog.org/ redirecting to biztech website.

Comment: Did you check http://packages.ubuntu.com? The package `libcloog-isl-dev` was removed from the Ubuntu repositories after 18.04, which is why apt in 22.04 cannot find it.

Comment: The website redirection strongly suggests that the cloog project was abandoned. Abandoned software is routinely removed from the Ubuntu repositories.